# Is it possible to save reports and data transformation steps in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have prepared some reports based on the files I prepared. I am wondering is it possible to save this report (measures and visualizations) and also the steps I made while transforming data? I want to be able to load new files (which in the structure are the same as the ones I used creating my report) and the data transformation and report done automatically on this updated data.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can just save your report with another name to copy all the transformation and calculation done in the first one.
But when you modify the transformation in one report. it dosen't automatically modify all the copy of that report.
If you want a centralised model for all your reports, you need to investigate to Analysis service ( Azure Analaysis service or the on-premise version Sql Server Analysis Service but it can be expensive )

Comment: @Carbon4horse i'm not sure how to save report with another name, cause i want to be able to load new files (the same structure as original), so i don't need to automatically modify the copy of the report.

Answer (score 1):

You can save it as a template - file extension pbit. It saves only the structure of the file, without actual data. When opening the report it refreshes it, and if there are parameters in the report (e.g. folder/file path or server address) it will refresh it considering the input values

you can read more here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-templates

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save your file as a template.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).